# Trouble outputting data with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am attempting to extract info about articles from this [site](https://www.artofmanliness.com/). I am a Scrapy newbie, and bit stuck as to why I don't getting any output, although I I am able to get all the correct URL outputted. I am unable to figure out what I am missing or need to change. Any help towards this end will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!!

I have the following code so far:

Here is my **spider**:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class ArticlesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'articles'
    allowed_domains = ['artofmanliness.com']
    max_pages = 200

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.max_pages):
            yield scrapy.Request('http://artofmanliness.com/articles/page/%d/' % i, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # AOM has a list of all articles in pages of about 189
        for article in response.xpath('//article[contains(@class, "aom-article-simple")]'):
            url = article.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()
            print(url)

            if url:
                yield Request(url=url[0], callback=self.parse_article)

    def parse_article(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//*[@id="post-title entry-title"]/header/h1//text()').extract()
        category = response.xpath('//*[@id="in-category"]/header/p[1]//text()').extract()
        date = response.xpath('//*[@id="single-date"]/header/p[2]/span[2]//text()').extract()

        yield {
            'Title': title,
            'Category': category,
            'Date': date,
            'URL': response.url           
        }
```

Here is **settings.py**:

```
BOT_NAME = 'aom'    
SPIDER_MODULES = ['aom.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'aom.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
HTTPERROR_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Comment: do you get error message? Always put full error message in question (not in comment) as text (not image)

Comment: why do yo use `url[0]` ?

Comment: I check HTML and I don't see element which could match to `//*[@id="post-title entry-title"]/header/h1//text()'` and the same problem can be with other xpathes.

Comment: @fura I wasn't getting any error messages just no output under title and categories.

Comment: @fura I use url[0] because the article tag happens to have two instances of the url, and returns a list of the two, so I just picked the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked HTML and there is no `title`

```
'//*[@id="post-title entry-title"]/header/h1//text()'
```

but

```
'//h1[@class="post-title entry-title"]/text()'
```

or even simpler

```
'//h1[@itemprop="headline"]/text()
```

And probably you have the same problem with other elements

---

**EDIT:**

There is no `category`

```
'//*[@id="in-category"]/header/p[1]//text()'
```

but

```
'//p[@class="in-category"]//a/text()'
```

---

There is no `date`

```
'//*[@id="single-date"]/header/p[2]/span[2]//text()'
```

but

```
'//p[@class="single-date"]//span[2]/text()'
```

or even simpler

```
'//span[@itemprop="datePublished"]/text()'
```

---

Minimal working code with `CrawlerProcess()`.

Everyone can paste all code in one file `script.py` and run it as `python script.py` without creating project.

I use `max_pages = 2` to test only few articles.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class ArticlesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'articles'
    allowed_domains = ['artofmanliness.com']
    max_pages = 2 # 200

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.max_pages):
            yield scrapy.Request('http://artofmanliness.com/articles/page/%d/' % i, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # AOM has a list of all articles in pages of about 189
        for article in response.xpath('//article[contains(@class, "aom-article-simple")]'):
            url = article.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()
            print('article url:', url)

            if url:
                yield Request(url=url[0], callback=self.parse_article)

    def parse_article(self, response):
        #title = response.xpath('//h1[@class="post-title entry-title"]/text()').extract()
        title = response.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="headline"]/text()').extract()
        
        category = response.xpath('//p[@class="in-category"]//a/text()').extract()

        #date = response.xpath('//p[@class="single-date"]//span[2]/text()').extract()
        date = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="datePublished"]/text()').extract()

        yield {
            'Title': title,
            'Category': category,
            'Date': date,
            'URL': response.url           
        }
        
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36",
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})
c.crawl(ArticlesSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: the answer worked great, thanks for the help!